# Delegate with radio buttons

Tags: python, pyqt5

I have the following code:

```
import datetime
from PyQt5 import QtCore
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *


class RadioDelegate(QStyledItemDelegate):
    def __init__(self, owner, chs):
        super().__init__(owner)
        self.items = chs

    def paint(self, painter, option, index):
        if isinstance(self.parent(), QAbstractItemView):
            self.parent().openPersistentEditor(index)
        super(RadioDelegate, self).paint(painter, option, index)

    def createEditor(self, parent, option, index):
        editor = QGroupBox(parent)
        #  editor.setMinimumHeight(38)
        editor.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        layout = QHBoxLayout()
        style = """
            padding: 0px;
            margin-top: 0px;
            outline: none;
            border: none
        """
        for k in self.items:
            rb = QRadioButton(k)
            rb.setStyleSheet(style)
            layout.addWidget(rb)

        editor.setStyleSheet(style)
        editor.setLayout(layout)
        return editor

    def setEditorData(self, editor, index):
        value = index.data(QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole)
        print("setEditorData-" + str(datetime.datetime.now()) + " " + str(value))

    def setModelData(self, editor, model, index):
        print("setModelData-" + str(datetime.datetime.now()))

    def updateEditorGeometry(self, editor, option, index):
        editor.setGeometry(option.rect)


class Window(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setGeometry(40, 80, 550, 250)

        self.table = QTableView(self)
        self.model = QStandardItemModel(self)
        self.table.setModel(self.model)
        self.table.setItemDelegateForColumn(3, RadioDelegate(self, ["abc", "xyz"]))
        self.populate()
        self.table.resizeRowsToContents()
        self.table.clicked.connect(self.on_click)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.table)

    def on_click(self, event):
        row = event.row()
        column = event.column()
        cell_dict = self.model.itemData(event)
        cell_value = cell_dict.get(0)
        print("Row {}, column {} clicked: {}".format(row, column, cell_value))

    def populate(self):
        values = [["1st", "2nd", "3rd", "radio"], ["111", "222", "333", ""], ["abc", "xyz", "123", ""]]
        for value in values:
            row = []
            for item in value:
                cell = QStandardItem(str(item))
                row.append(cell)
            self.model.appendRow(row)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Window()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

And I get the look of the edited cell (4th column), which is not acceptable:

cell with radio buttons

[image]

How can I get rid of these margins or this padding? Or make the group box extend to cover the whole cell?

I have tried to manipulate style sheets, as you can see, but with no effect.
Of course, I can use "editor.setMinimumHeight(38)", but the top margin or whatever it is, still remains, and I can select the whole cell (not only the radio buttons).

By the way! Do you know how the paint method should look like to display radio buttons also in display mode?

Comment: I don't get what you show

Comment: I cannot reproduce this (using qt-5.13.2 on linux). Try using `QItemDelegate` instead of `QStyledItemDelegate`. Or perhaps try adding `QApplication.setStyle('fusion')` before creating `app`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the margins of the layout too:

```
    def createEditor(self, parent, option, index):
        editor = QGroupBox(parent)
        #  editor.setMinimumHeight(38)
        editor.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        layout = QHBoxLayout()
        layout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
```

When a layout is created it has no margins, but they will change as soon as it is applied to a widget:

From the [`getContentsMargins()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlayout.html#contentsMargins) documentation:

> By default, QLayout uses the values provided by the style.

These values are provided by the following QStyle's [pixelmetrics](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstyle.html#PixelMetric-enum): `PM_LayoutLeftMargin`, `PM_LayoutTopMargin`, `PM_LayoutRightMargin`, `PM_LayoutBottomMargin`. They all depend on the style internal parameters, the level of the widget (if it's a top-level widget - a "window" - or a child) and the dpi of the screen.

While newly created layouts usually return (0, 0, 0, 0) from `getContentsMargins()`, internally their value is actually -1. When the layout is applied to a widget, Qt will use the style's fallback values *only* if they've not been set to a value >= 0.
So, the margin has to be explicitly set even for 0 values to ensure that no margin actually exists; conversely, the style's default values can be restored by setting each margin to -1.

---

A couple of suggestions, even if they're not related to the actual question.

First of all, don't try to open the persistent editor within the paintEvent. Despite the fact that the method you used wouldn't work anyway, paintEvents happen very often, and creating a new widget inside a paintEvent would require another call to the paintEvent itself, potentially creating an infinite recursion (luckily, Qt would ignore the openPersistentEditor if it already exists, but that's not the point).

Whenever you're using a complex widget, it's better to set the background of the editor, otherwise the item's text might be visible under the editor in most styles. Also, there's no need for a QGroupBox for this situation, a simple QWidget will suffice.
With CSS you can just do this (there's no need to apply the style to the children):

```
        editor.setStyleSheet("QWidget { background: palette(base); }")
```

If you don't need specific customization, you can avoid stylesheets at all and just set the autoFillBackground property:

```
        editor.setAutoFillBackground(True)
```

Finally, the biggest issue of this kind of implementation is that if the column is not wide enough, some radio buttons might become invisible as using `setGeometry` will "clip" the contents to the item rectangle.
To avoid that, you can adjust the geometry rectangle to accomodate all its contents, based on its minimum size hint:

```
    def updateEditorGeometry(self, editor, option, index):
        rect = QtCore.QRect(option.rect)
        minWidth = editor.minimumSizeHint().width()
        if rect.width() < minWidth:
            rect.setWidth(minWidth)
        editor.setGeometry(rect)
```

Unfortunately, this will not be a very good thing if you want to show the editor even in "display mode", as you requested.
To do that in a good fashion while keeping a good user experience, things will be a bit more complex: the editor should be always be clipped when the item is not the current index, and automatically "resized" when some interaction is needed; also, if a hidden radio is selected, the user might click on an unchecked one, which will make *that* radio checked, without knowing the previous status.

To do so I'm using an event filter that will "clip" the widget using [`setMask()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#setMask-1) if it has no focus, and show all of it whenever it gets it. Since radio buttons can steal focus, I'm setting their focusPolicy to `NoFocus`. This also allows me to check if the widget has received a click to toggle radio buttons or just to start the editing; in that case, the click event will be ignored.

```
class RadioDelegate(QStyledItemDelegate):
    def __init__(self, owner, chs):
        super().__init__(owner)
        self.items = chs

    def createEditor(self, parent, option, index):
        editor = QWidget(parent)
        editor.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        editor.setAutoFillBackground(True)
        # create a button group to keep track of the checked radio
        editor.buttonGroup = QButtonGroup()
        # adding the widget as an argument to the layout constructor automatically
        # applies it to the widget
        layout = QHBoxLayout(editor)
        layout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        for i, k in enumerate(self.items):
            rb = QRadioButton(k)
            layout.addWidget(rb)
            # prevent the radio to get focus from keyboard or mouse
            rb.setFocusPolicy(QtCore.Qt.NoFocus)
            rb.installEventFilter(self)
            editor.buttonGroup.addButton(rb, i)
        # add a stretch to always align contents to the left
        layout.addStretch(1)

        # set a property that will be used for the mask
        editor.setProperty('offMask', QRegion(editor.rect()))
        editor.installEventFilter(self)
        return editor

    def eventFilter(self, source, event):
        if event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.MouseButtonPress:
            if isinstance(source, QRadioButton):
                if not source.parent().hasFocus():
                    # the parent has no focus, set it and ignore the click
                    source.parent().setFocus()
                    return True
            elif not source.hasFocus():
                # the container has been clicked, check 
                source.setFocus()
        elif event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.FocusIn:
            # event received as a consequence of setFocus
            # clear the mask to show it completely
            source.clearMask()
        elif event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.FocusOut:
            # another widget has requested focus, set the mask
            source.setMask(source.property('offMask'))
            # update the table viewport to get rid of possible
            # grid lines left after masking
            source.parent().update()
        return super().eventFilter(source, event)

    def updateEditorGeometry(self, editor, option, index):
        rect = QtCore.QRect(option.rect)
        minWidth = editor.minimumSizeHint().width()
        if rect.width() < minWidth:
            rect.setWidth(minWidth)
        editor.setGeometry(rect)
        # create a new mask based on the option rectangle, then apply it
        mask = QRegion(0, 0, option.rect.width(), option.rect.height())
        editor.setProperty('offMask', mask)
        editor.setMask(mask)

    def setEditorData(self, editor, index):
        value = index.data(QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole)
        if value in self.items:
            editor.buttonGroup.button(self.items.index(value)).setChecked(True)

    def setModelData(self, editor, model, index):
        button = editor.buttonGroup.checkedId()
        if button >= 0:
            model.setData(index, self.items[button], QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole)


class Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        # ...
        # I just added an option for the purpose of this example
        self.table.setItemDelegateForColumn(3, RadioDelegate(self, ["abc", "xyz", 'www']))
        # ...
        # open a persistent editor for all rows in column 4
        for row in range(self.model.rowCount()):
            self.table.openPersistentEditor(self.model.index(row, 3))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @musicmate. This is far more than I would expect.